# Internal microphone on IdeaPad Pro 5 not working

Tags: drivers, pulseaudio, microphone

I just bought a Lenovo IdeaPad Pro 5 (16ARP8) and installed Ubuntu 22.04.3. Everything is working fine until I tried to hop onto a call and noticed that the internal microphone doesn't work and in fact isn't recognized by the system at all.

[image]

It's not a hardware defect as the microphone is working as intended in Windows:

[image]

```
patrick@patrick-IdeaPad-Pro-5-16ARP8:~$ inxi -Fxz
System:
Kernel: 6.2.0-37-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME 42.9
Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 83AS v: IdeaPad Pro 5 16ARP8
serial: <superuser required>
Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0T76463 WIN
serial: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO v: L0CN25WW date: 05/23/2023
Battery:
ID-1: BAT0 charge: 13.6 Wh (17.5%) condition: 77.5/75.0 Wh (103.4%)
volts: 14.9 min: 15.6 model: SMP L22M4PF5 status: Discharging
CPU:
Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 7735HS with Radeon Graphics bits: 64
type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3 rev: 1 cache: L1: 512 KiB L2: 4 MiB L3: 16 MiB
Speed (MHz): avg: 1546 high: 1600 min/max: 1600/4828 boost: disabled
cores: 1: 1371 2: 1600 3: 1600 4: 1391 5: 1600 6: 1581 7: 1600 8: 1419
9: 1381 10: 1600 11: 1600 12: 1600 13: 1600 14: 1600 15: 1600 16: 1600
bogomips: 102206
Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
Device-1: AMD Rembrandt vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel
bus-ID: 73:00.0
Device-2: Acer Integrated RGB Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
bus-ID: 5-1:2
Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
compositor: gnome-shell driver: gpu: amdgpu resolution: 2560x1600~120Hz
OpenGL:
renderer: REMBRANDT (rembrandt LLVM 15.0.7 DRM 3.49 6.2.0-37-generic)
v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
Audio:
Device-1: AMD vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
bus-ID: 73:00.1
Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_pci_acp6x v: kernel bus-ID: 73:00.5
Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel
v: kernel bus-ID: 73:00.6
Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.2.0-37-generic running: yes
Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
Device-1: Realtek vendor: Lenovo driver: rtw89_8852ce v: kernel port: 4000
bus-ID: 01:00.0
IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
bus-ID: 3-3:2
Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: down
bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: no
address: <filter>
Drives:
Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 11.3 GiB (2.4%)
ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Lenovo model: UMIS RPJTJ512MKP1QDY
size: 476.94 GiB temp: 28.9 C
Partition:
ID-1: / size: 95.56 GiB used: 11.23 GiB (11.8%) fs: ext4
dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
ID-2: /boot/efi size: 256 MiB used: 70.2 MiB (27.4%) fs: vfat
dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
Alert: No swap data was found.
Sensors:
System Temperatures: cpu: 38.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 38.0 C
Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
Processes: 398 Uptime: 4m Memory: 13.33 GiB used: 2.23 GiB (16.7%)
Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.4.0 Packages: 1810 Shell: Bash
v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13
```

Here's what I tried so far:

1. Installed PulseAudio Volume Control and checked there

[image]

I also tried to unlock the channels and set the left one to zero (was recommended somewhere):

[image]

2. Changed the input channel in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf according to this tutorial: https://candid.technology/ubuntu-microphone-not-working/
3. Tried to install the missing codecs but for my sound card there was no suitable codec name here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html

At least I found out that the codec apparently is a Realtek ALC257
[CODE]cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: ATI R6xx HDMI
Codec: Realtek ALC257[/CODE]

4. Stumbled upon a similar problem here about ALC257 and tried it's solution: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1904213

The temporary solution was posted here (although I think it doesn't apply to my hardware): https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/2460#issuecomment-779212719

5. Disabled Realtek driver module according to: http://mreen.epizy.com/SoundFixTips2.html?i=1
6. Updated SOF driver according to a tutorial with a similar problem and ALC256: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtop...?f=42&t=373391
7. Booted the newest Ubuntu 23.10 from USB and checked the sound settings which was still empty
8. I've found an Arch forum that discussed exactly the issue I'm facing with ALC257: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2056452 Apparently ALC257 is the headphone/audio jack and not the internal microphone. My output is almost the same but instead of the ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor from answer #5 I have an Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor:

```
lspci | grep Audio
73:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1640
73:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 60)
73:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

The solution in the thread was to enable snd_pci_acp6x driver and its DMIC support to the kernel config. I'm hoping to do s.th. similar with the Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor. Now I've never done anything like this before and am also not sure how to do it in Ubuntu.

Can someone tell me how to do it (the system is new, if it breaks then no worries) or have any other ideas to try?

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

I have the same model and OS. I experience the same problem. My configuration is ([detailed HW info here](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=be74f076bd)):

```
product: 83AS (LENOVO_MT_83AS_BU_idea_FM_IdeaPad Pro 5 16ARP8)
base board product name: LNVNB161216
vendor: LENOVO
version: IdeaPad Pro 5 16ARP8

OS: Ubuntu 23.10 (mantic), Linux kernel:6.5.0-15-generic
```

I suspect the kernel doesn't match our notebook product as described in this bug: [216270 – Builtin microphone doesn't work on ASUS Zenbook S 13 OLED 2022 (UM5302TA)](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216270). You can see here in the [kernel source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/sound/soc/amd/yc/acp6x-mach.c#L58).

The kernel's bug is mentioned in this thread: [[SOLVED] ALSA: no input through internal microphone (Ryzen 6000) / Laptop Issues / Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=278886).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can somewhat follow what the other threads are talking about but actually have no idea on how to do that in Ubuntu. I've found the thread from the archlinux forum already (see no. 8 in my post) which seems to detail the problem. But still it doesn't say how it is done (might be different in archlinux?). Have you figured out how to apply it in Ubuntu?

Comment: Hi @Patrick, unfortunately the fix doesn't seem very easy. We need to recompile the kernel with our notebook product name added to the quirks table. I've found this blog post: [Fixing issues on Thinkpad Neo 14 running Linux | Kevin Jiang's Technical Blog](https://jiangsc.me/2023/06/03/thinkpad-neo-14-issue-fix/).
I've added the following kernel parameter: _snd_rn_pci_acp3x.dmic_acpi_check=1_. I had no success with it. Based on this reading: [Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Pro 14ACN6 - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_IdeaPad_5_Pro_14ACN6#Internal_Microphone)

Comment: Just to add: There's no change between Ubuntu and ArchLinux in our case. They both use the Linux kernel.

Comment: Hi @Patrick, I've added a comment to [this kernel bug 216925](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216925#c6). There's a patch for our model. I cannot say at the moment in which kernel's version will be included.